# Implementing Virtual Keyboard Android to PC

Tags: java, android, sockets, keyboard

I'm attempting to use my android phone as a keyboard for my PC. 
This is done over a local WiFi connection using sockets to create the client/server connection.

I'm using a textwatcher to pick up the change in characters in an editText and then sending those over to the server which then uses a robot class to write that onto the PC. This is all using a Softkeyboard on the android phone. 
The issue is that when writing in editText only one character gets sent. and picked up by the server.

e.g. I type on the android phone "a" and the respective keypress will be simulated on the server. If I then type another character it does not read that character but if I delete the "a" and then type another character it will send that character.

Below is the Client side of the code, the Android application.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnKeyListener {


private final static int portNumber = ****;
private final static String hostName = "192.168.0.8";
private final static String cTest = "Connection Test";
Socket socket = null;
private static String TAG = "test";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            try {
                Log.i(cTest, "attempting to connect");
                socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
                Log.i(cTest, "Connected");

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connected Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                editText.addTextChangedListener(editTextWatcher);

           } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e(cTest, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }.start();
}


 private TextWatcher editTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

  private void sendTextToServer(String send) {

      BufferedWriter bw = null;

      String textChange = send;


      try {
          bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
          bw.write(textChange);
          bw.newLine();
          bw.flush();

      } catch (IOException e) {

      }
  }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
            Log.d(TAG, s + " Character Read");

                String test = s.toString();
                this.sendTextToServer(test);
    }
};


@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    return false;
 }
}
```

The following code is the server side code which is being done in eclipse.

```
public class ListenServerMain {

private static boolean ifConnected = true;
private final static int portNumber = ****;
public static String readIn;
private static Socket client = null;
private static ServerSocket server = null;
private static BufferedReader in = null;
private static Robot robot = null;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
                robot = new Robot();
                server = new ServerSocket(portNumber);


                System.out.println("Listening on port :****");
                client = server.accept(); //loops until a client server connection is established
                System.out.println("Client connected");

                //Receive a message from the client
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

                while(ifConnected)
                {

                        readIn = in.readLine();     //reads the input received

                        if(readIn.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
                                {
                                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);

                                }
                        if(readIn.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
                                {
                                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B);
                                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_B);
                                }
                        if(readIn.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
                                {
                                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                                }
                        if(readIn.equalsIgnoreCase("BS"))
                        {
                            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
                            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
                        }
                                }                               
                                System.out.println("Unable to read user Input");            //if it can't read the input from the Client
                                System.exit(-1);                                            //system exits


                System.out.println("Server Ended");
                System.exit(-1);

            }   
                catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Can't open the Socket");
                    System.exit(-1);                            
            }
                catch (AWTException e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to create Robot");
                    System.exit(-1);                            
            }





    }
}
```

Is there any way in which I can successfully read and send each character entered in the editText field?

If any further clarification about this is necessary let me know.

Thanks

Comment: instead of sending each character why dont you send every thing inside edit text?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried that but couldn't figure out how to successfully send the whole string

Comment: if you are sending each character how will you implement back/clear button?

Comment: I could check if the lengths of the editText before and after and if it is less after then send a predefined string over to simulate a delete press. Though I haven't attempted this yet as I've been trying to get basic letters to work first